# Какой GUI лучше для C++?

Tags: c++, gui, поиск-библиотек

Я знаю 2 реализации Gui в C++ возможно есть ещё какие то с лицензией MIT ImGui,nuklear.
Если вы знаете GUI библиотеки для C++ с MIT лицензией.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот не mit, но буст, что думаю, тоже нормально - http://nanapro.org/en-us/

bsd лицензия - https://www.ultimatepp.org/

Comment: Краткий и толковый (как мне показалось) [обзор лицензий](https://www.itweek.ru/foss/article/detail.php?ID=194342)

Comment: boost лицензии там нет. не считается:)